# create polylines with different colors in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, line

I have one function which creates poly line & adds that polyline to map

```
function makeRoute(e)
{
    if(pointsSelection.length > 0)
    {
        pointsSelection.push(e.target.getLatLng());
        var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointsSelection, {
        color: 'blue',
        weight: 5,
        smoothFactor: 1
        });

        firstpolyline.addTo(map);

        pointsArrayCollection.push(pointsSelection);
        polyArrayCollection.push(firstpolyline);

        selection = [];
        pointsSelection = [];
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select more than one point");
    }
}
```

my problem is that It adds line with same color every time.

I want to add poly lines with different colors every time.

So how can I change color of polyline dynamically.

Comment: You could use something like this function in place of 'blue'. If you want something a little less random, I suggest you define a color palette as an array and select sequentially from that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this for creating dynamic colors

```
var color;
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
color= "rgb("+r+" ,"+g+","+ b+")";
```

then use this

```
var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointsSelection, {
    color: color,
    weight: 5,
    smoothFactor: 1
 });
```

I think this answer will helps you